# Windows Forms Application в Rider

Tags: c#

В Visual Studio есть Windows Forms Application. А есть ли это в Rider? Никак не могу найти.

Comment: Насколько знаю в ридере нет визуального конструктора.

Comment: все формы (кнопки, окна и тд) нужно прописывать вручную. имхо пользуйтесь VS остальное от лукавого

Comment: Зато есть в MonoDevelop.

Comment: @Alex78191 кстати да, хорошая альтернатива если нужна кроссплатформа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привожу страничку jetbrains с Questions and Answers по Rider от 28 Ноября 2016 :

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/11/28/introducing-rider-the-new-net-ide-webinar-recording-and-qa/

Среди вопросов присутствует и ваш :

> Q: Are you also developing a GUI designer like in Visual Studio for WinForms, WPF etc?
>
> A: Yes, we’re looking at how we can support at least previewing WinForms/WPF/Xamarin Forms. We’re not sure we’re going to make it for the first release though.

Перевод ответа :

> Да, мы ищем варианты, как поддерживать хотя бы предварительный просмотр WinForms / WPF / Xamarin Forms. Мы не уверены, что мы сделаем это для первого релиза.

И далее в комментариях но уже позднее поднят тот же вопрос, вот ответ :

> We expect to add a GUI previewer later this year or in early 2018. However, the release that is coming in September or October (2017.2) will not yet include any of this.

"Мы планируем добавить графический интерфейс в конце этого года или в начале 2018. Однако выпуск, который поступит в сентябре или октябре (2017.2), пока не будет включать в себя все это."

Итог : Полноценного IDE с потдержкой GUI для кросплатформенной разработки не стоит ожидать ранее 2018.

Comment: Вот уже 2018, а поддержки все нет.

Comment: А теперь они обещают в начале 2019-го